# How to call useState from another Page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, use-state

Bascially whenever I deleted an item in my handleDelete function it would route back to the homePage and I wanted to display a message  that says your product succesully deleted for about 5 seconds.

In my index.js I first set message to false. and inside my ProductAttribute whenever I click it the set message will be true and will show the message in Index.js/ in my UI.

my handleDelete function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Header, Button, Modal } from "semantic-ui-react";
import axios from "axios";
import baseUrl from "../../utils/baseUrl";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function ProductAttributes({ description, _id }) {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
    const router = useRouter();

async function handleDelete() {
    const url = `${baseUrl}/api/product`;
    const payload = { params: { _id } };
    await axios.delete(url, payload);
    router.push("/");
    setMessage(true);
    setTimeout(function () {
        setMessage(false);
    }, 5000);
}
```

while in my Index.js. The setMessage in my useState isn't getting called from ProductAttributes file.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ProductList from "../components/Index/ProductList";
import baseUrl from "../utils/baseUrl";
import { Message, Container } from "semantic-ui-react";

function Home({ products }) {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                {message ? (
                    <Message
                        deleted
                        icon="checked"
                        color="red"
                        content=" Product Successfully Deleted"
                    />
                ) : (
                    ""
                )}
            </Container>
            <ProductList products={products}></ProductList>
        </>
    );
}
```

How can I make this setMessagebe callable in ProductAttributes? am I doing it right with the Parent to Child Relation or should I bring the useState in the child to parent?

Comment: Please post code as text instead of a screenshot image.

Comment: I will edit it. wait

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's edited already. Do you have the answer?

Comment: @BloodyLogic I already edited it and turn it into code.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an handler in the `Home` Component like this

```
const handleSetMessage = (message) => {
    setMessage(message)
}
```

this handler will be responsible of updating the value of `message` state in the `Home` component. and this methode you can pass it as props to `ProductList` component which will also pass it down to `ProductAttribute`. This will force you to pass props till the lowest level in your APP where you need to call that method.

Or you can take advantage of [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API which will allow you to have access to that method without passing it down as props.

```
const MessageContext = React.createContext("");
```

And in the `Home` component you use that Context like this

```
function Home () {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    
    const handleSetMessage = () => {
        setMessage(true)
    }
    return <MessageContext.Provider> value={{setMessage: handleSetMessage}}>
         // The code which render the component child goes here.
    </MessageContext.Provider>
}
```

After that in your `ProductAttribute` Component you access to that `setMessage` function like this

```
import React, { useContext} from 'react';


const ProductAttribute = (props) => {
    const { setMessage } = useContext(MessageContext);
    
    const handleDelete = async () => {
        // Here you call the setMessage function which will update state in the `Home` Component
        setMessage();
    } 

    return <div>

    </div>
}
```

Comment: what happen to  <Message
                    // deleted
                    icon="checked"
                    color="red"
                    content=" Product Successfully Deleted"
                /> ? Why is it gone?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make this setMessagebe callable in ProductAttributes?

A good practice would encompass you creating a handler function which delegates to the setState function and passing the reference of this function to ProductAttributes as props.

this is an example:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
const handleIncrementCounter = () => setCounter(counter + 1);
<ChildComponent handleIncrementCounter ={handleIncrementCounter }/>
```

then in ChildComponent..

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
   return (
      <button onClick={props.handleIncrementCounter}/>
   );
}
```

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I don't get it. How will I call that to ProductAttributes from Index.js ?

Comment: so i will import index.js to ProductAttributes?

Answer (score 0):

Once you show you a message, wait for 5sec to close the message and redirect back to the home directory. just place the `route.push('/')` inside `setTimeout` so it will wait for 5sec to be redirected.

```
async function handleDelete() {
    const url = `${baseUrl}/api/product`;
    const payload = { params: { _id } };
    await axios.delete(url, payload);
    setMessage(true);
    setTimeout(function () {
        router.push("/");
        setMessage(false);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: It should route to the index first router.push("/") and then the message will display. and the setMessage says it is not a function. How can I call the setMessage from Index.js to ProductAttributes.js? .

Comment: You should pass `setMessage` props to `ProductAttributes` component, then it would work!

Comment: function ProductAttributes({ description, _id, setMessage }) I passed it and it says's setMessage is not a function

Comment: https://github.com/GrizzlyBear-Michaelangelo/Ecommerce.git here is it. sorry for the late reply.