# Passing a single boolean useState between two pages using Material UI web components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I've been trying to pass in a boolean `useState` between two pages, using the best practice shown here: [How to call useState from another Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990652/how-to-call-usestate-from-another-page)

My main objective is to show a success alert on a different page, once a form is successfully submitted on `"./demo"`

**Demo.js** holds a dialog with a `submit button` that sets the `setSuccess` to true.

```
import Alert from "./alert";

export default function AlertDialog() {
  const [success, setSuccess] = React.useState(false); // <- Hides and Shows the Alert Message

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    return (
      <Alert
        setSuccess={() => {
          setSuccess(true); // <- How I am trying to setSuccess to true.
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
        <DialogActions>
          <Button
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            color="primary"
            autoFocus
            component={RouterLink}
            to={"/"}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
  );
```

**Alert.js** has an alert message that appears once `success` is set to true.

```
export default function Alerts(props) {
  // const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const { success, setSuccess } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Collapse in={success}>
        <Alert
          action={
            <IconButton
              aria-label="close"
              color="inherit"
              size="small"
              onClick={() => {
                setSuccess(false);
              }}
            >
              <CloseIcon fontSize="inherit" />
            </IconButton>
          }
        >
          Form Successfully Submitted
        </Alert>
      </Collapse>
      <Button
        disabled={success}
        variant="outlined"
        component={RouterLink}
        to={"/demo"}
      >
        Go Back to Submit Form
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
```

;
}

Could someone explain how I can have the success alert appear after submission? If you wish to take a deeper dive, please visit here https://codesandbox.io/s/alert-test-qhkbg?file=/alert.js

Comment: Have you thought of using a Context around your routes and saving the variable there?

Comment: @RichardHpa I haven't heard of "Context", as I'm fairly new to React. But thank you, I will search it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is passing state through React Router. Right now your alert isn't updating because your URL is changing when the submit button is pressed.

[Check out this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/alert-test-forked-npfdv?file=/alert.js). I'm passing a message and a property to get the alert to render within the `/` route with different logic.

This is the key snippet:

```
<Button
  color="primary"
  autoFocus
  component={RouterLink}
  to={{
    pathname: "/",
    state: { message: "hello, i am a state message", open: true }
  }}
>
  Submit
</Button>
```

And then in your alert component at the url `/` you can:

```
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.location.state?.open ? setOpen(true) : setOpen(false);
  }, [props]);

  // This message is what is being passed. Could be anything.
  console.log(props.location.state);
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. I was able to find multiple solutions around this answer.